# Single-sign on options for MS CRM dynamics

Tags: authentication, ldap, dynamics-crm, moodle

I'm looking into having services like Moodle and Drupal integrate with my MS CRM database of users and authenticate against it.  So far, other than a webservices API I can build on (which sounds like a lot of work/bugs) I can't find a lot here. Is there a third-party module/service that'll provide some level of standardized single-sign on, like maybe LDAP or CAS or Shibboleth. Microsoft has some identity server product that might integrate with their CRM and might give me LDAP, but I'm not really sure if that'll even work.

If not, what's my best option to code this? I was thinking doing a database query every x minutes from CRM's MSSQL and dumping the users table into, say, an openLDAP server. Then I could authenticate against that LDAP. It would be read-only, just for authentication.

I'm working from a lot of assumptions here, so please feel free to correct me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MS Dynamics CRM authenticates against Active Directory. All users in CRM must also exist in AD.

Since this means you'll already have a domain controller in place, perhaps you can configure Drupal, Moodle and other apps to authenticate against the DC as well? AD can be treated as an LDAP source in many instances, and many open-source apps include LDAP modules.

It will be much easier to get your OSS talking to AD, than it will be to get MSCRM to talk to other authentication systems.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized Moodle supports External Database authentication. So I should be able to connect to my MSSQL server and just read the users table.

Won't work for Drupal and other applications, but its at least something.